# How to make area from specific node or relation, using it's element id number in Overpass QL?

Tags: overpass-api

I can make an area in Overpass QL, using name and relation attributes (tags) filter of element, something like this:

```
area["name:en"="Moscow Oblast"]["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="4"]->.region;
(node(area.region)[place="city"];node(area.region)[place="town"];);
out;
```

But searching via name is not so stable, and will broke if element name is changed. So much better (for performance too) is to make an area from element id. Here is example of searching relation via it's element id:

```
rel(51490);
out;
```

And can't understand, how to pass element type and id to area query? Something like this:

```
area(rel(51490))->.region;
(node(area.region)[place="city"];node(area.region)[place="town"];);
out;
```

or other variants like `area["id"=51490]->.region;` or `area["type"="rel"]["rel"=51490])->.region;` don't works.

Can anyone give me an example, how to make area from OSM element by it's id?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to quick answer of @mmd from Slack, here is working solution:

```
rel(51490);map_to_area->.region;
node(area.region)[place="city"];
out;
```